# Convert mimetype to file extension

Tags: xcode, nsurlconnection, mime-types, file-extension

how to convert mimetype to file extension in xcode
for example i have this code

```
File Extension     MIME Type

aifc                audio/x-aiff
avi                 video/x-msvideo
gz                  application/x-gzip
jpg                 image/jpeg
```

Xcode

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
        NSString *mime      = [response MIMEType];
        NSString *extension = @"" // how to covert it ?!
}
```

Comment: I would create a dictionary and just ask value for key: mime.
like: `NSString *extension = [dictionary objectForKey: mime];`

Comment: is there any method to do that without making dictionary ?

Comment: `CFStringRef mimeType = (CFStringRef)@"audio/x-aiff";
CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, NULL);CFStringRef extension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);`

Comment: ctrl + c would not work, if you not include <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> or <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

include `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` or `<CoreServices/CoreServices.h>`
then just following code:

```
CFStringRef mimeType = (CFStringRef)@"audio/x-aiff";
CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, NULL);
CFStringRef extension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
```

Comment: I try to edit this one by adding the Swift 4 version but was rejected. Told me put it as another answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4:**

Import CoreServices

```
response.mimeType // is Optional<String> - some : "audio/mpeg"
```

And how to get mp3 is:

```
guard let mime = response.mimeType,
      let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mime as CFString, nil),
      let ext = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti.takeRetainedValue(), kUTTagClassFilenameExtension) else {
   return
}

ext.takeRetainedValue() // is "mp3"
```

PD: Consider that Xcode won't get extensions of unknown file like .Storyboard or .cert in this case will exit in the Guard return.

Comment: As of now, in Swift, I needed to `import CoreServices`